# Syriac Abbreviation Mark

Tags: xetex, unicode, polyglossia

I'm trying to implement in XeLaTeX the Syriac Abbreviation Mark (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_Abbreviation_Mark).

The code I came up with is the following:

```
\catcode`^^^^070f=13
\chardef\zwj="200D
\def^^^^070f#1 {\zwj\aemph{#1}\ }
```

Now I can use the control character in the text (assuming I have a Syriac font):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}

\setmainfont{Estrangelo Edessa}


\catcode`^^^^070f=13
\chardef\zwj="200D
\def^^^^070f#1 {\zwj\aemph{#1}\ }

\begin{document}

ܫܠ܏ܡܳܐ ܫܠܡܐ.

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Example of Syriac Abbreviation Mark]

This is not perfect for two reasons. First, it requires a space to end the control sequence (in fact, it should be ended by any non-Syriac character). Second, ideally the result should be an overline with 3 dots in it (beginning, end and middle - see above Wikipedia article for example).

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As it stands the code is completely wrong and it's difficult to understand what it should do.

Comment: I realized now that I could simplify the code using the \aemph command defined in Polyglossia. This would yield the following code: 
    \catcode`܏=13
    \newcommand{\zwj}{‍}
    \def܏#1 {\zwj\aemph{#1}\ }

Comment: ``\catcode`13= `` is meaningless. Or, better, it has a meaning that's surely not what you want. Also `\def1# {` is illegal. It seems that you're mixing left-to-right with right-to-left.

Comment: There is a problem here with the rendering of this Unicode character (which is Right-To-Left and thus messes up the order). It just makes the SAM character  (U+070F) an active character. The second command defines \zwj as a substitute for the ZWJ character (U+200D). The last command defines the the SAM character followed by an argument and then a space as  {\zwj\aemph{#1}\ }.

Comment: You can use the `^` convention: ``\catcode`^^^^070f=13`` and then `\def^^^^070f#1{...}`; you can also say `\chardef\zwj="200D` which is easier. May you try it and expand to a complete example?

Comment: So here is the resulting code:
`\catcode`^^^^070f=13
\chardef\zwj="200D
\def^^^^070f#1 {\zwj\aemph{#1}\ }`    Assuming I have a Syriac font installed I can now type ܫܠ܏ܡܳܐ in the body of the document to get the desired result (an overline over the two last letters).

Comment: Ideally SAM should be implemented by the fonts, unfortunately OpenType does not have a provision for such a character (there was recently a proposal to add a new feature for it, but it can be years before such feature is widely implemented, if ever) `:(`

Comment: @KhaledHosny Has the situation improved in the intervening years?

Comment: @DanielLyons: Newer versions of HarfBuzz and newer versions of the OpenType spec support it now, see https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/issues/141. Didn’t test it in XeTeX though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implemented in the font now (per Werner's question).

[image: abbrev mark]

Random unicode input, compiled with xelatex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
%Options:
%‣ numerals = western (i.e., 1234567890), eastern (for which the Oriental Arabic
%numerals are used: ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠), or abjad.  .
%v1.0.1
%Commands:
%\abjadsyriac ‣ \abjadsyriac (see section 9)
%\aemph ‣ \aemph (see section 6.1).

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=abjad]{syriac}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\fgfontc[Scale=2.3,Script=Syriac,Colour=green]{Noto Sans Syriac Eastern}
\newfontfamily\fgfontck[Scale=2.3,Script=Syriac,Colour=blue]{Noto Sans Syriac Eastern}\newfontfamily\fgfontd[Scale=4.5,Script=Syriac,Colour=red]{Noto Sans Syriac Eastern}
\newfontfamily\fgfontdk[Scale=4.5,Script=Syriac,Colour=blue]{Noto Sans Syriac Eastern}

\setmainfont{Noto Sans Syriac Eastern}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}


\begin{english}
Syriac font,
with \textbackslash kern and \textbackslash llap commands. 
\end{english}

\fgfontc ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧܦܗܡܠܡܐ\kern-1.25pt\llap{\fgfontck ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧܦܗܡܠܡܐ}

܏ܘܗܖ܏ܛܚܙ܏ܩ܏ܨܧ܏܏܏ܤ

\fgfontd  ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧܦܗܡܠܡܐ\kern-1.45pt\llap{\fgfontdk ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧܦܗܡܠܡܐ}

\end{center}

\begin{english}
Syriac font, regular and bold:
\end{english}


ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧ ܦܗܡܠܡܐ

\bfseries
ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧ ܦܗܡܠܡܐ 

\mdseries\Large
ܞ܏ܞܭܬܩܨܧܦܗܡܠܡܐ 

\bfseries
ܞܭܬܩ܏ܨܧ܏ܦܗܡܠܡܐ 
܏ܘܗܖ܏ܛܚܙ܏ܩܨܧܤ

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a TikZ method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xspace}
\tikzstyle{zwj}=[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=base]
\tikzstyle{zwjdot}=[circle,draw,fill,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=1pt]
\newcommand{\zwj}[1]{%
   \tikz[baseline]{
      \node[zwj] (text) {#1};
      \useasboundingbox (text.base west) rectangle (text.north east);
      \draw ([yshift=2ex]text.base west) -- ([yshift=2ex]text.base east)
         node[pos=0,zwjdot] {}
         node[pos=1,zwjdot] {}
         node[pos=0.5,zwjdot] {};
   }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
foobar         & puckluck \\
\zwj{foo}bar   & \zwj{puck}luck
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

At this point the descenders are changing the vertical alignment.  I'll try more later.

[image: sample code output]

Comment: The line looks beautiful, but this has the unfortunate side effect of not respecting the text order (which is Right-to-Left in Syriac). By the way, one should probably call your macro \sam as it stands for Syriac Abbreviation Mark (ZWJ = Zero-Width-Joiner, which is responsible for the contextual shaping of the letters).

Comment: @Ariel: Hm.. I'll have to think more about RTL.  But I did fix the baseline problem.

Answer (score 1):

OpenType have already introduced 'stch' feature which used to generate this special overline, if you use some TeX engines as latest version of XeTeX you could get proper effect.

Comment: Can you provide an example showing that?